# Run a Javascript in timed intervals?

Tags: javascript

How can I run a Javascript function with per-set time delays, without using any framework?

I have a Ajax script which will fetch the no of online users from server. This script i want to run in a regular timed delays.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be with [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval):

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log("run every second");
}, 1000);
```

This will run the given code at the specified time interval over and over.

Answer (score 2):

```
var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
  console.log("foo");
}, 1000);
```

And stop

```
window.clearInterval(interval);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval` to do this.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval

Answer (score 0):

```
var int = self.setInterval(askQuestion,1000);

function askQuestion() {
 // do something... code to be implemented.
}
```

Will be call `askQuestion()` every 1000 milliseconds (1 seconds) for example..

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var intervalVariable=setInterval(function(){
   //Your operation goes Here
  },1000); // executes every 1000 milliseconds(i.e 1 sec)

function stopTimer()
{
   clearInterval(intervalVariable); // To clear TimerInterval/stop the setInterval Function
}
</script>
```